# From which book is this quote? - “Nothing is more despicable than respect based on fear.”

Tags: existentialism, camus

I know it’s a quote of Camus, but could you refer to the book?

Answer (score 1):

It is in his autobiographical [Carnets](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnets_(Albert_Camus)), more specifically in [Carnets I](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22625768), under November 39. Camus did not write this for any book though, these "Carnets" were notes he used to write in personal notebooks, and were only posthumously compiled for publishing.

The original goes like this:

> Rien n'est plus méprisable que le respect fondé sur la crainte

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out.